# Fine uploader get params from MVC endpoint

Tags: azure, fine-uploader

I tried to set fine uploader parameter as follow

```
callbacks: {
        onUpload: function (id, name) {
            var params = {fileSize: uploader.getSize(id), fileName: name };
            uploader.setUploadSuccessParams(params, id); // Work
            uploader.setParams({ newPar: "321" });  // Doesn't work

        },
    }
```

I can get success parameters from success endpoint as follow

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("success")] //Succes endpoint
        public async Task OnUploadSuccess()
        {
            var fileName = Request.Form.Get("fileName");
            var fileSize = long.Parse(Request.Form.Get("fileSize"));
        }
```

But can't do the same for params

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("sas")] //Request endpoint
    public ContentResult CreateSas()
    {
        var param= Request.Form.Get("newPar"); //Doesn't work
    }
```

Any help for how can I get this parameter in the MVC controller

Comment: What does the request look like according to the browser?

Comment: this is request data from fiddler 
GET /uploads/sas?bloburi={my blob uri}&_method=PUT&qqtimestamp=1478510982532 HTTP/1.1

Comment: You are using fine uploader azure. This should have been mentored in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setParams` sends parameters to Azure as headers, attached to the "PUT BLOB" request. You cannot send custom params to your SAS endpoint. https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1224